# Merge Specifying Column Order

Tags: sas

I have two SAS data sets similar to this:

```
DATAONE            DATATWO  
-----------        ------------------  
ID  A  C  E        ID  B  D  F  
1   x  x  x        1   x  x  x     
2   x  x  x        2   x  x  x    
3   x  x  x        3   x  x  x
```

They're of equal length row-wise and have the same sorted values for ID in each column. Initially, to combine the data I went with the following simple one-to-one merge statement:

```
data COMBINED;
    merge DATAONE DATATWO;
run;
```

This produces an output as follows:

```
COMBINED           
--------------------      
ID  A  C  E  B  D  F  
1   x  x  x  x  x  x 
2   x  x  x  x  x  x
3   x  x  x  x  x  x
```

This has all of the data I want, but the columns are in the wrong order. My ideal output would reorganize the columns like this:

```
COMBINEDTWO           
--------------------      
ID  A  B  C  D  E  F  
1   x  x  x  x  x  x 
2   x  x  x  x  x  x
3   x  x  x  x  x  x
```

However, I'm not really sure how to reorganize the columns like that. Checking the SAS website there is something called a match-merge but that seems to just be used for merging the rows correctly (in case there are missing lines or something). Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Note: I'm pretty much a complete beginner to SAS having only used it for a few days so my apologies if this is a really simple question and I missed the answer when searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you probably want to do a match-merge:

```
data COMBINED;
    merge DATAONE DATATWO;
    by id;
run;
```

A 1 to 1 merge risks problems if a) one dataset is not sorted the way you think it should be, or b) one dataset is missing one or more IDs.  Match merge makes sure the IDs match.  It does require the datasets to be properly sorted prior to the merge.

Secondly, you cannot automatically reorder the variable names directly.  You need to somehow construct a properly ordered list of variable names, depending on how you want to order them.

One way to do that would be to construct a list and use it in a RETAIN statement.  This statement actually does something else, but it is convenient to use for reordering variables.

```
data COMBINED;
    retain ID A B C D E F;
    merge DATAONE DATATWO;
    by id;
run;
```

That is okay, but it would be nice to move it out of the data step and have it somewhere that you can edit it if it changes more easily, especially if you need to use this in several places.  One way to handle that is to put it in a macro variable:

```
%let varorder = A B C D E F;
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
data COMBINED;
    retain ID &varorder.;
    merge DATAONE DATATWO;
    by id;
run;
```

Note I leave ID out of it, as that probably needs to be up front in any event.  That'll be important later.

Now, that probably works for your short example, but might be impractical for larger datasets.  How about grabbing that order from the datasets?

```
proc contents data=dataone out=var_dataone(keep=name);
run;
proc contents data=datatwo out=var_datatwo(keep=name);
run;

data vars;
set var_dataone var_datatwo;
by name;
if name='ID' then delete;
run;
```

Okay, now we have a dataset with our names, in the proper order.  So we can pull that into a macro variable a few different ways; here's one.

```
proc sql;
 select name into :varorder separated by ' ' 
   from vars
   order by name;
quit;
```

Now we have `&varorder` constructed from the datasets' contents.  It's in alphabetical order; if you wanted it in some other order you'd want to reorder it how you like.  You could use `varnum`, which is on the contents output (add it to the `keep` statement) if you want to try and keep it in the order that is on the dataset.

Comment: This solved my problem perfectly, and provided a ton of other useful information that went above and beyond the original scope of my question. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem.  Be aware that `retain` does affect how variables act during manipulation in the data step if they are _not_ brought in from a merge or set statement, ie, if you create a new variable during that merge statement; if it's on the `retain` statement, it will act slightly differently than a normal new variable (specifically, it will keep its value from row to row if not otherwise set).

Answer (score 1):

Joe's answer is the one you want, but as an aside you can use SQL to reorder columns in a dataset. Using your dataset as an example:

```
proc sql;
 create table COMBINED_REORDER as
 select ID, A, B, C, D, E, F 
 from COMBINED
quit;
```